# Returning "void" or "null" from a method

Tags: java, c++, c, methods, return-value

Here I have few Questions:

1)I tried to return a `null` value from a method,something like this(only when `TypeCasted` into object) :

```
 public static Object returns()
{
   return (Object)null ;
}
```

And stored the Object:

```
 ...main()..{
 Object obj=  returns();
 ...}
```

When i checked:

```
  if( obj.equals(obj))
```

Threw a `NullPointerException`

But,

```
 if(null==null)
 System.out.println("works");
```

Compiled and gave right output.Any reasons for this?

2) Also, when i tried:

```
 public static Object returns()
{
  return (Object)void ;
}
```

Gave me `Syntax Error`.Any reasons?

3) Can this behaviour be different in `C/C++` ?Or any other `OO` Language?

Comment: Because they are different languages based on different language rules they are bound to show different behavior.

Comment: `this behaviour be different in C/C++`

Comment: `obj.anything` when `obj` is null won't work. `.equals` is different than `==` in almost every case.

Comment: @AlokSave In which language we can try this out?

Comment: The three languages mentioned handle things totally differently. You should ask about one at a time.

Comment: @Guy can you give a Example code?

Comment: `return (Object)void` <- `void` is not an expression.

Comment: Note - `a == null`, `b != null` -> `b.equals(a)` should work (and return false) (as long as whomever coded the method is a decent coder).

Comment: In C++, as in Java, you can't call member functions (aka methods) on a null pointer (or dereference it in any other way), but you get undefined behaviour rather than an exception. In C, there's no equivalent to methods, but dereferencing a null pointer again gives undefined behaviour. In all three languages, `void` is a type name, not a valid expression, so it can't be cast to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not call `equals` on `null` instead you should use `==`. Note that calling `==` and `equals` is not the same. `==` compares references while `equals` is a method which by convention compares **values**. As the null object has no value this has no meaning for it.

Void is not a value in any language and so it can not be casted to anything(in this case `Object`).

In C++ to return NULL you will have to return a pointer. To compare the returned object you will have to type something like:

```
 if( *obj == *obj)
```

And again this will fail as obj is NULL. In any language I know you will have to do an explicit check for null before comparing.

EDIT: come to think a bit what you try will work in `ruby`

Comment: Hmm right! what about the other two cases?

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
if(obj.equals(obj))
```

It's true that the default `equals` implementation just uses `==` to check if the two objects (actually, the two references) are actually referring to the same object in memory, but it's nonetheless a call to an instance method, which is bound to fail with a `NullPointerException` if it's called over a `null`.

```
 if(null==null)
```

instead doesn't give any problem, since you are not calling any instance method, you are just comparing addresses.

2) `void` is just a keyword used to mark a function returning nothing<sup>1</sup>; it doesn't make any sense to try to return it. `null`, instead, marks an object reference as pointing to nothing, that's an entirely different concept.

3) In C++ there's no default "equals" method, and the whole object model is based on *value types* (in Java, instead, you normally work with references to objects), so it's difficult to make a precise comparison.<sup>2</sup>

In C++ an object (or a reference) is *guaranteed* to be a "valid" object (=there's space allocated for it and a constructor has run), so there's no possibility of getting an hypothetical equivalent of `NullPointerException` when calling an instance method over an object.

On the other hand, it's entirely possible to have a *pointer* that is `NULL`, and in such case you go into undefined behavior (usually a crash) if you try to dereference it in some way (e.g. via `*` or `->`)<sup>3</sup>.

As for the equality checks: the `==` operator for objects is not implemented by default, so comparing objects for equality makes sense only if the implementor of the class actually wrote an overload for `operator==`; as for pointers, the `==` operator is provided by the language itself (and cannot be overridden), and it actually compares the two addresses.

---

1. In contrast to C and C++, where `void` is considered a type (in particular, "an incomplete type that cannot be completed"), in Java [it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681568/in-java-can-void-be-considered-a-primitive-type), although in some respects it can be considered as such.
2. In C there are no classes or methods *period* - it's not an OO language; still, most of the discussion that follows applies to `struct`s and accessing their fields.
3. Although... if an instance method isn't `virtual` and doesn't use any field of the object (=the `this` pointer isn't dereferenced in any way), in most implementations you may get away with calling an instance method on a `NULL` pointer. Also, by "formally dereferencing" a pointer you can get away with creating a "null reference", that will probably cause trouble when it's used. But in both cases it's still undefined behavior - i.e., it's not correct, although no preventive checks are normally performed, favoring performance over strict rules enforcing.

Answer (score 0):

`(Object)null` is null, meaning you cannot use any methods on it as it does not exist.

As for the syntax error, in Java `void` is a type,not a value, so you cannot return `void`.

Comment: Can we do this in c/c++?

Comment: @joeyrohan: No, you can't dereference null pointers or use `void` as an expression in those languages either.

Comment: Older languages like Pascal would make distinction between procedures and functions. Both were parameterized code routines, but function would be allowed to return a result to caller in analogy to mathematical functions. C and latter languages unified the concept creating the `void` type to mean that the function does not return a value